# Maximize does not finish or does not work

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum, maximize

I need to maximize the following expression over the two variables $d$ and $a$, in terms of the parameters $t, m, k$:

```
Maximize[{(d*(1-m/k)^d)*a*(t-t*(1-m/k)^d-((d^2*m^2*(1-m/k)^d)/(1-(1-m/k)^d))*a*t*Sqrt[t*(1-m/k)^d]), 10<=k<=t/10 && 1<=m<=Sqrt[k] && t>=100 && 0<a<1/k},{a,d}]
```

I do not receive any output with Mathematica (Cloud) and I do not understand why.
More precisely, I need to maximize the above expression over $a$ and $d$, while minimizing it over $m,k,t$. I tried to create a function of $a$ and $d$ maximizing the expression over $m,k,t$ and then to minimize such function over $a,d$, but I do not get any result.

Finally, I would like to test if there exists a pair of constant values $\alpha,\beta>0$ and a pair of values for variables $a,d$, such that, for all $t,m,k$ in their ranges, the above expression is in the interval $\left[\alpha\sqrt{tmk},\beta\sqrt{tmk}\right]$. Should I use the command `FindInstance` in this case?

Comment: You have a symbolic expression with 5 variables, some of which you're trying to maximize over, the remainder over which you're trying to minimize. This likely generates a huge symbolic expression which takes a large amount of memory and time to process, which is why you get no result. Your best bet might be to try to set some of the parameters to numerical values and solve for the rest. I.e. start by picking a reasonable value for k, then m, maybe t as well. FindInstance looks for specific solutions, rather than a general one, so it might give you a subset of solutions. Might as well try it.

Comment: Thank you @jdp . What should I do was happy with a rought approximation of the symbolic expression I am looking for?

Comment: For your final question, can you try 10^4 iterations with random values for t,m,k to see if you can find values for α,β,a,d? Print each time you find a value that pushes the edge of the envelope. 10^4 won't guarantee that is the limit but it usually tells me more about the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to get a symbolic expression. I tried setting {t -> 200, k -> 15, m -> 2} and obtained a nasty looking nonlinear expression with terms like d const^d, etc. I tried Maximize and it returned unevaluated quickly. Equations of that form can't easily be solved symbolically in closed form in general. I did a 3D plot and succeeded, and got a solution numerically via NMaximize.: {10433.3, {a -> 0.0000890625, d -> -36.2949}}. The documentation for Maximize indicates you'll get a solution for linear/polynomial input, so you might do some sort of power expansion - maybe.

Comment: Thank you @jdp !

Comment: Thank you @Bill !